# How can I stop a website preloader loading more than once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load a website preloader only once using session storage but it's not working.

I added a preloader to a website. The preloader works as expected (shows when page is loading, disappears when page finishes loading). However, I am finding that once the site has loaded and one navigates to another page of the site and then back again to the homepage (linked to the preloader), the preloader shows again but this time it doesn't always disappear. Sometimes it just sits on "loading" and nothing happens. I tried to solve this problem by having the preloader load only once. I tried using session storage to achieve this but it's not working. Where am I going wrong? This is my first website and I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div  class="preloader">
    <div class="preloader4"></div>
    <div id="loadingText"><p>Loading</p></div>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/preloader.js"> </script>

</body>

</html>
```

styles.css

```
.loading {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.preloader {
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 11000;
}

#loadingText {
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align:center; 
 position: absolute;
 top:50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 color: white;
 font-family: "Exo 2", Sans-serif;
 font-weight: 800;
 font-style: italic;
 z-index: 12000;
}

.preloader4 {
  position: absolute;
  top:-100%; right:-100%; left:-100%; bottom:-100%;
  margin:auto;
  z-index:0;
  padding: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 65% 15%,  #eed0e4 2px, #fdacd4 10%, #FF69B4 40%, #ca4487 80%);

  -webkit-animation: pulse 1s infinite ease-in-out alternate; /* Safari & Chrome*/
  -moz-animation: pulse 1s infinite ease-in-out alternate; /* Firefox */
  -ms-animation: pulse 1s infinite ease-in-out alternate;/* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: pulse 1s infinite ease-in-out alternate;/* Opera */  
  animation: pulse 1s infinite ease-in-out alternate; /* W3C */
  z-index: 12000;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  from { transform: scale(0.8); }
  to { transform: scale(1.2); }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {
  from { transform: scale(0.8); }
  to { transform: scale(1.2); }
}

@-o-keyframes pulse {
  from { transform: scale(0.8); }
  to { transform: scale(1.2); }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  from { transform: scale(0.8); }
  to { transform: scale(1.2); }
}
```

preloader.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {  

$(window).on('load', function(){

if (sessionStorage.getItem('dontLoad') == null) {

  $(".preloader").fadeOut(0, function() {
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    });

 sessionStorage.setItem('dontLoad', 'true');
}

});

});
```

Comment: You're only removing the preloader when `sessionStorage.getItem('dontLoad') == null`, every time afterwards the javascript doesn't attempt to hide the element.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that what you've built is correct (minus the `sessionStorage` part). Every time the page is visited, a loading indicator is displayed until the Javascript on the page has been downloaded and executed.

Unless you were planning on conditionally displaying the loading message with a server-side language based on the session variable you're not really able to achieve the functionality you're looking for.

Even with the sessionStorage check you have (which I think is the wrong way around) - this isn't done until the Javascript is loaded, so you'll still see the loader when you open the page.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS make it display:none

```
.preloader {
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  display:none;
  z-index: 11000;
}
```

In Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
 $(".preloader").show();

  $(".preloader").fadeOut(0, function() {
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Mohan for your suggestion. I tried that but it doesnt seem to be displaying at all now. I have also tried adding cookies but cant get that to work either.

Comment: Try this. 

$(document).ready(function() {  
 $(".preloader").show();
});


$(window).on('load', function(){
  $(".preloader").fadeOut(0, function() {
      $('body').removeClass('loading');
    });
})

Comment: Thanks Mohan. I also tried that, preloader still not showing. No idea why. Bit of a puzzle. :/